# WordPress custom SQL case ordering priority

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I hope someone can help me. I'm trying to do a custom SQL query in WordPress and have the results ordered by a predefined priority.

The example search string is 'EU Directive' and the query needs to look at the post's title and a custom field (text field) named 'intro'.

I need the ordering to work by prioritising results with a title or intro matching the full string in some way, ahead of results which contain only 1 of the 2 words in the search string.

The query works, but the ordering does not. Results which only match 1 of the 2 words are being pulled out ahead of a result which has the full string 'EU Directive' in the 'intro' field.

I thought the query below would set up the ordering correctly but it's not unfortunately.

Can anyone see any glaring errors? Any help would be greatly appreciated at this stage.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS     mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( 

(wp_posts.post_title LIKE 'EU Directive %') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND     CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE 'EU Directive %'))     ) 
OR ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE 'EU Directive%') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND     CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE 'EU Directive%'))  ) 
OR ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive %') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive %'))    ) 
OR ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive,%') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive,%'))    ) 
OR ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive.%') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive.%'))    ) 
OR ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive%') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive%'))  ) 
OR ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE 'EU %') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE 'EU %'))    ) 
OR ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU %') OR ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU %'))    )
) 

AND wp_posts.post_type = 'documents' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 

ORDER BY 

(CASE 

WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE 'EU Directive %' THEN 1 
WHEN (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE 'EU Directive %') THEN 2 
WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE 'EU Directive%' THEN 3 
WHEN (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE 'EU Directive%') THEN 4 
WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive %' THEN 5 
WHEN (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive %') THEN 6 
WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive,%' THEN 7 
WHEN (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive,%') THEN 8 
WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive.%' THEN 9 
WHEN (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive.%') THEN 10 
WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% EU Directive%' THEN 11 
WHEN (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'intro' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '% EU Directive%') THEN 12
ELSE 13
END), 
wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, in your `CASE` statement you are trying to output an ordering value, based on the conditions that are met. The problem is, from the `CASE` statement you get a number: let's say it's 1. In that case, you are just doing `ORDER BY 1`, which means "by the first column". You should use that `CASE` as a field in your `SELECT`, and then put the field's name in the `ORDER BY` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *, (CASE WHEN... THEN ...) AS position FROM wp_posts ...) data
ORDER BY data.position, data.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Thanks so much Aioros. I had a feeling I had misunderstood the whole idea - I looked at what WordPress produces in the default search functionality and worked backwards from there. So I need to rework the SELECT statement. I'll give it a go! Thanks again